# Attribute border exists, but can not be used for this element

Tags: asp.net

When trying to validate my site, I get the following error:

- Line 188, column 134: Attribute "border" exists, but can not be used for this element.

  ~/images/gobutton.jpg" border="0" />

My asp.net source looks like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 

ImageUrl="~/images/gobutton.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click"

ValidationGroup="search"/>
```

Why is the border element being rendered by the imagebutton?

Is there anyway to control this?

---

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article identifies the same issue

[XHTML Validation Fails due to  renders a BORDER="0" output](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/ac098c63-61ff-4b53-b5ad-72cb2eb0f7f2)

Comment: Yeah, this nonsense really puts me off ever using ASP.NET. I mean I know I can disable it with a clienttarget declaration, but Microsoft, you really thought sniffing for browser name and serving different HTML to them was a good idea? In *this* century? With all the UA-blocking and proxying/caching problems that involves? And then you decide that rather than reserving the invalid markup for known-bad browsers, you give that to all unknown UAs by default? Seriously?

Comment: The explanation given in that thread that the content was “appropriate for older browsers that should be compliant with HTML 4.0 Transitional” is also utterly bogus. <input type="image" border="0"> is just as invalid in HTML 4.01 as it is in XHTML 1.0 (since they are the same DOM just serialised differently). No browser has needed `border="0"` since Netscape 4 (which isn't supported anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. If anyone encounters this issue you can resolve it by adding the following to the system.web section of your web.config file. I found this solution [here](http://www.solutioncottage.com/ShowSolution.aspx?solID=161) so kudos to Mikael @ [www.solutioncottage.com](http://www.solutioncottage.com/Default.aspx)

```
<system.web>
   ...
    <browserCaps>
      <case match="W3C_Validator*">
        TagWriter = System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter
        W3CDomVersion = 1.0
      </case>
    </browserCaps>
   ....
</system.web>
```